# Why my deep learning model cannot be trained in 10 iterations?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

My deep learning model is used to segment the CT images. But the loss value is always very high. To debug the program, I used the same input images to observe the output and the loss value of the 10 iteration are all the same, which means the network's parameter didn't change at all. Could you please tell me why my model cannot be trained ? Is the reason that I didn't use the DataFrame method?
The code shows as follows:

```
for ite in range(iteration):
    print("=====iteration", ite, "=======")
    weights = few_shot_model.conditioner(condition_input)
    output = few_shot_model.segmentor(query_input, weights)
    # out = F.softmax(output, dim=1)
    print("out.shape, y2.shape:", output.shape, y2.shape)
    print("y2.unique:", torch.unique(y2))
    loss = loss_func(output, y2, binary=True)
    optim_s.zero_grad()  # clear gradients for this training step
    optim_c.zero_grad()  #
    loss.backward()  # backpropagation, compute gradients
    if phase == 'train':
        if epoch <= warm_up_epoch:
            optim_s.step()  # apply gradients
            optim_c.step()
            scheduler_c.step()
            scheduler_s.step()
        elif epoch > warm_up_epoch and change_model:
            optim_n.step()
        print("loss.item", loss.item())
```

Comment: Are you normalizing the inputs? That could be the reason for very high loss value.